# Multiple Constructors Class Setters C++

Tags: c++, constructor

So, I just had a question about my professors feedback on one of the programs we did. I didn't quite understand her feedback on what she meant by putting setters functions in the second constructor. Here is what she said:

> Next time be sure to do the Reading and Preparation assigned before you attempt a lab. Read the assignment carefully.
>
> The problem says the overloaded constructor (constructor #2) should call the setter functions.
>
> The overloaded constructor (constructor #2) was not tested. Create an object with the overloaded constructor like so:    Inventory itemTwo(666,3,.99);
>
> Nice class, nice main program and coding style.

This was the problem:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWxN2.png)

And lastly, here's my code:

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
 private:
  int itemNumber;   //Private Class Members
  int quanity;
  double cost;
 public:
  Inventory();   //Public Member Functions
  Inventory(int i, int q, double c);
  void setItemNumber(int);
  void setQuanity(int);
  void setCost(double);
  int getItemNumber() const;
  int getQuanity() const;
  double getCost() const;
  double getTotalCost() const;
};

int main()
{
 int itemNum;
 int qty;
 double price; 
 Inventory itemOne;   //Declares itemOne and itemTwo being an Inventory class objects
 Inventory itemTwo;
 
/****************************************************************************/
 
 cout << "Please Enter Data For Item One\n";     //Data entry for Item One
 cout << "Enter item number: ";
 cin >> itemNum;
  
 while (itemNum < 0)           //Safegaurds for data
 {
  cout << "Please enter a non-negative item number: ";
  cin >> itemNum;  
 }
 
 cout << "Enter quanity: ";
 cin >> qty;
 
 while (qty < 0)
 {
  cout << "Please enter a non-negative quanity number: ";
  cin >> qty;
 }
 
 cout << "Enter price: ";
 cin >> price;
 
 while (price < 0)
 {
  cout << "Please enter a non-negative price: ";
  cin >> price;
 }
  
 itemOne.setItemNumber(itemNum);   //Passes All Data To Correct Functions
 itemOne.setQuanity(qty);
 itemOne.setCost(price); 
 cout << endl;          //Formatting
 
/****************************************************************************/ 

 cout << "Please Enter Data For Item Two\n";    //Data Entry for Item Two
 cout << "Enter item number: ";
 cin >> itemNum;
  
 while (itemNum < 0)
 {
  cout << "Please enter a non-negative item number: ";
  cin >> itemNum;  
 }
 
 cout << "Enter quanity: ";
 cin >> qty;
 
 while (qty < 0)
 {
  cout << "Please enter a non-negative quanity number: ";
  cin >> qty;
 }
 
 cout << "Enter price: ";
 cin >> price;
 
 while (price < 0)
 {
  cout << "Please enter a non-negative price: ";
  cin >> price;
 }
 
 itemTwo.setItemNumber(itemNum);   //Passes All Data To Correct Functions
 itemTwo.setQuanity(qty);
 itemTwo.setCost(price);
 cout << endl;          //Formatting
 
/****************************************************************************/ 

 
 cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

 //All input displayed here
 cout << "Here's the data you entered for item one:\n";
 cout << "Item Number: " << "  " << itemOne.getItemNumber() << endl;
 cout << "Item Quanity: " << "  " << itemOne.getQuanity() << endl;
 cout << "Item Cost: " << "  " << "$" << itemOne.getCost() << endl;
 cout << "Item Total Cost: " << " " <<"$" << itemOne.getTotalCost() << endl << endl;
 
 cout << "Here's the data you entered for item two:\n";
 cout << "Item Number: " << "  " << itemTwo.getItemNumber() << endl;
 cout << "Item Quanity: " << "  " << itemTwo.getQuanity() << endl;
 cout << "Item Cost: " << "  " << "$" << itemTwo.getCost() << endl;
 cout << "Item Total Cost: " << " " <<"$" << itemTwo.getTotalCost() << endl;
 
 return 0;
}

Inventory::Inventory()       //Default Constructor
{
 itemNumber = 0;
 quanity = 0; 
 cost = 0;
}

Inventory::Inventory(int i, int q, double c) //Constructor #2
{
 itemNumber = i;
 quanity = q; 
 cost = c;
}

void Inventory::setItemNumber(int i)   //Re-Evaluates For a Negative Number and
{            //Passes User's Entered Data to the Private class
 if (i >= 0)
  itemNumber = i;
 else
  itemNumber = 0;
}

void Inventory::setQuanity(int q)    //Re-Evaluates For a Negative Number and
{            //Passes User's Entered Data to the Private class
 if (q >= 0)
  quanity = q;
 else
  quanity = 0;
}

void Inventory::setCost(double c)    ////Re-Evaluates For a Negative Number and
{            //Passes User's Entered Data to the Private class
 if (c >= 0)
  cost = c;
 else
  cost = 0;
}

int Inventory::getItemNumber() const   //All 'Getter' Functions to Display Object's Data
{            //Whilst Keeping Data Integrity With 'const'
 return itemNumber;
}

int Inventory::getQuanity() const
{
 return quanity;
}

double Inventory::getCost() const
{
 return cost;
}

double Inventory::getTotalCost() const   //Calculates Total Cost and Returns
{
 return cost * quanity;
}

/*
-----------------------------------------------------
Please Enter Data For Item One
Enter item number: 1303
Enter quanity: 10
Enter price: 2.50

Please Enter Data For Item Two
Enter item number: 5676
Enter quanity: 54
Enter price: 5.65

Here's the data you entered for item one:
Item Number:            1303
Item Quanity:           10
Item Cost:              $2.50
Item Total Cost:        $25.00

Here's the data you entered for item two:
Item Number:            5676
Item Quanity:           54
Item Cost:              $5.65
Item Total Cost:        $305.10
-----------------------------------------------------
Please Enter Data For Item One
Enter item number: 7456
Enter quanity: 10
Enter price: 10.9

Please Enter Data For Item Two
Enter item number: 0293
Enter quanity: 5
Enter price: 109.23

Here's the data you entered for item one:
Item Number:            7456
Item Quanity:           10
Item Cost:              $10.90
Item Total Cost:        $109.00

Here's the data you entered for item two:
Item Number:            293
Item Quanity:           5
Item Cost:              $109.23
Item Total Cost:        $546.15
-----------------------------------------------------
*/
```

Comment: _"Next time be sure to do the Reading and Preparation assigned before you attempt a lab. Read the assigment carefully"_ Well, that's pretty clear.

Comment: ._. not talking about that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor probably meant that you should call the setter functions in the constructor instead of setting the values directly:

```
Inventory::Inventory(int i, int q, double c)    //Constructor #2
{
    setItemNumber(i);
    setQuantity(q); 
    setCost(c);
}
```

Comment: Hm, I thought I tried doing that originally but gave me compile errors.. Going to re-test it now.

Comment: You should note the biggest reason to do so is that your `set` functions have additional logic, that won't allow you to set parameters `< 0`, whereas your current overloaded constructor will gladly accept `Inventory inv(-1, -1, -0.1);` Had you called the `set` functions, it would have set them all to `0`.

Comment: ahhhhh, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks a Ton, whole chapter was awfully confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

She's right. You are taking user input, therefore you must validate it with your setters, you created them for a reason.

```
Inventory::Inventory(int i, int q, double c)    //Constructor #2
{
    setItemNumber(i);
    setQuantity(q); 
    setCost(c);
}
```